# Run a PHP function on every X pageview (alternative to cron)

Tags: php

I am doing some error checking which involves a single database query. The error is to test whether the cron job has stopped working, and so by its nature I do not want to use a cron job to run the PHP function.

Instead of running the database call on every pageview, I thought a different approach of "running once every X pageviews" would be a good alternative to lighten load.

This isn't something I have heard of, or could look for - which makes me think there's a better alternative. Very interested to hear pros/cons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually chances are you are using the exact same mechanism already in your every call, if you are using PHP sessions. PHP session garbage collector does exactly the same thing - randomly deletes expired sessions.

See: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/sessionhandler.gc.php

> Cleans up expired sessions. Called randomly by PHP internally when a session starts or when session_start() is invoked. The frequency this is called is based on the session.gc_divisor and session.gc_probability configuration directives.

To do this simply roll a random number and check if it is above the "percentage" you need:

```
$roll = mt_rand(1, 100);

if ($roll > 90) {
  // This will fire in 10% of cases
  // Do what you need
}
```

It is important to consider, though, that:

1. Even if you set it to fire in 99% of cases, it can still end up not firing for a 100 years straight. This is pretty much like probability theory works.
2. If your traffic is low (in general or on some particular day), your checking code might not fire and you will possibly miss an error.
3. Also there's always a possibility that your check will be launched twice simultaneously by two different users viewing a page at the same moment. So you might want to ensure this doesn't cause you any problems, especially if you do any updates in your check.
4. Be careful not to do heavy lifting on your checks, because this way some of your requests will experience much higher response times (duuuh, I know, but for completeness. And since it actually bit me a couple of times).

Points 1 and 2 move this mechanism from "reliable" category to "not very reliable, either for something that is not super important anyway or as an additional safeguard for another, reliable mechanism".

So, I would say - weigh everything, and if you still want it - go ahead and use this mechanism.